# Weather and climate of an Earth-like planet orbiting an orange dwarf

Tags: planets, climate, atmosphere, earth-like, weather

I am creating a solar system with fictional planets as a setting for my space novel.

Luckily I have some nice tools for creating quite accurate astronomical data. The planet where my protagonists live is very similar to Earth, but it's a little smaller and closer to its sun (0.5 AU from an orange dwarf). A day, on this planet, is 58 hours long and the mean surface temperature is slightly above Earth's. The atmospheric composition is identical to ours, but atmospheric pressure is 0.7 atm rather than 1 atm. The axis of the planet is 23 degrees, so we have seasons. Gravity is 0.7 G rather than 1 G.

I know that it's almost impossible to imagine a precise model of weather and climate, however, I'd like to have your help to define if the planet would have a similar hydrologic cycle with similar climatic dynamics.

The hydrologic coverage of the planet is 90%.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Please note that, as stated in our [help], we answer only 1 question per post. I have closed your post so that you can edit it to satisfy the criteria. Once it is edited it will enter the reopen queue and, if reopened, it will be possible to answer it.

Comment: A good idea to hammer out your problem might be to post the question in WB Meta. Other users will help you formulate your post to fit the rules of the stack..  https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: Hello Alessandro, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. I'm going to invite you to delete your question and re-ask it in our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/40609). Questions about climate are, perhaps, the most complex to ask. By definition, asking about the entire climate for an entire planet violates the [help/dont-ask]'s "book rule," meaning it's too broad or is asking too much (libraries of books have been written about Earth's climate). Developing a climate for a fictional world takes many steps because (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... you must consider the details you've provided plus the map of land vs. water, altitude of the land, depth of the water, the presence of moons, the development of oceanic currents, volcanism, the impact of inhabitants, and many other factors. In other words, the question could be answered trivially (if you want Earth-like, use Earth's climate) or by answering a series of questions that delve into the complexities of your world. My point is that we try not to close new user questions because it's too often interpreted as a punishment.

Comment: JBH, I notice that it's very easy to contradict your guidelines. Anyway, I haven't demanded a mathematical answer, but, instead, requested some ideas (and L.Dutch gave me a good example of a good answer)

Comment: I regret, Alessandro, that a new user is involved in a discussion like this. The Stack has a history of closing questions just like this. It's not an issue of mathematical precision - its that you've provided so little information about a subject so large that in one question no answer is valid per SE's guidelines. Per the [tour], SE is not a discussion forum and per the [help/dont-ask], questions leading to all answers having equal value are prohibited. That's why we discourage brainstorming questions in the [help/on-topic]. We are, perhaps sadly, stuck with SE's model.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the ambient conditions (temperature, pressure and change of irradiation over the year) it is plausible that water will be present in all 3 phases at the same time and that therefore there might be some hydrologic cycle of some sort.

The greatest difference I can imagine is that, due to the scarcity of landmasses, there will be more predominant wind patterns.

More or less what happens on Earth with the "[roaring forties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Forties)" in the South hemisphere, it's very likely to happen here all over the planet: prevalent winds flowing in a fixed directions with high intensity due to the lack of appreciable landmasses attenuating or deviating them.

Comment: Deleting things is one of the reasons why [that Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10318/40609) was asked. And in doing so, you denied the OP an explanation of why he/she can no longer delete their question.

Comment: @JBH, explaining things is one thing. Denigrating answers is another. You should be already familiar with the CoC

Comment: You have done something obviously wrong. Where much is given (like that moderator diamond) much is required and you should be held to a higher standard regardless the CoC. You and Monty have begun setting bad standards for the Stack. It's a very real problem when the folks who are setting those bad standards can and do erase data from the public's memory so the public can no longer judge if someone was "denigrating."

Comment: Roaring twenties (= the [mad 1920s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaring_Twenties), "les années folles") → roaring forties (= the everlasting circle of winds between the 40th and 50th southern parallels).